# How do I combine tryCatch and UseMethod?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write some S3 methods, and I'd like them to share common error handling code. This seemed like the obvious way to me:

```
myMethod <- function(x) {
    tryCatch(UseMethod("myMethod", x), error=function(e) paste("Caught:", e))
}

myMethod.default <- function(x) print("Default.")
```

But it doesn't work, since `UseMethod` doesn't like being wrapped in `tryCatch`:

```
myMethod(0)
[1] "Caught: Error in UseMethod(\"myMethod\", x): 'UseMethod' used in an inappropriate fashion\n"
```

Does anyone have any advice on where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it.

```
myMethod <- function(x) {
  fn <- function() UseMethod("myMethod", x)
  tryCatch(fn(), error = function(e) paste("Caught:", e))
}
myMethod.default <- function(x) print("Default.")

myMethod(structure('1', class='default'))
# [1] "Default."
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much much neater than my workaround!